# General rule for generating a convergent set of random numbers

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I want to generate a large series of random numbers between 0 and 100 that converges towards an average of 70.

I've observed that if I take the square root of a sequences of random numbers between 0 and 100 squared, I converge on an average of 200/3. If I take the cube root of a series of random numbers between 0 and 100 cubed, I converge on an average of 300/4.

I could fudge my way to converging on 70, but I'm pretty sure there must be a general rule for this sort of thing.

Comment: There's a wide range of possibilities.  You might want to be more explicit about any requirements you have about the distribution of numbers within the interval $[0, 100]$.  For example, a random sequence consisting of only the number $70$ technically satisfies your requirement, but I'm guessing that wouldn't not be satisfactory.

Comment: Some possible distributions: 1.  Constant value of $70$.  2.  Uniform on $[40, 100]$.  3.  Distribution with PDF $f_X(x) = \frac{7}{300} (x/100)^{4/3}$ on $[0, 100]$.  4.  Beta$(7, 3)$ distribution for $X/100$.

Comment: Initially, my thought was that I wanted a function that guaranteed every number 0-100 was possible, but that with sufficient iteration, the mean of those numbers would converge on 70. What I'm seeing with my first pass is very high-end heavy.

Ideally, what I'd like is a function that returns numbers where the mean converges on 70 and the distribution converges on "skewed normal" (something close to a standard normal distribution, but skewed to center on the target mean.)

Comment: You might try the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) then.  [Here's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Beta(7,+3)+distribution) a plot of the distribution for the parameters $\alpha = 7, \beta = 3$.  You'll have the scale the values by $100$, but otherwise, it might be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: The OP has edited the question and this answer is no longer relevant. Thanks for the upvote.

By converging, do you mean the expected value?

If yes, I can readily point out probably the simplest family of distributions, the uniform distributions. Infinitely many have $\mu=70$. The rule is as follows: select a number $x$. Take an uniform distribution from $\mu-x$ to $\mu+x$ so from $70-x$ to $70+x$. The mean ($\mu$) of the numbers is $70$.

If not, please clarify what you want to converge.